# Is there a kind of functor has a function (monad<A>, function A -> monad<B>) -> Monad<B>

Tags: functional-programming

There's a pattern in my code (Java) which looks like:

```
private M<State2> augmentFromDS3(M<State1> state1) {
    return state1.flatMap(this::transform1);
}


private M<State3> validatePersonType1(M<State2> state2) {
    return state2.flatMap(this::transform2);
}

private M<State2> 
transform1(State1 state1) {
}

private M<State3> 
transform2(State2 state2) {
}
```

There's also a version which calls map.

This feels like there's a functional pattern (like a monad transformer, comonad, etc.) here that has been found before. However, I don't know what the name is for the kind of thing I think is there.

Comment: That's just the type of `flatMap` that you are already using? Functors that have this kind of functions are called *monads* :-)

Answer (score 3):

By just looking at the title of your question I think this is the [bind](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads) (>>=) function of monad in Haskell (or flatMap in Scala):

```
(>>=)  :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Comment: This is pretty hilarious to anyone interested.